# Can I change my bundle display name (text under the app) when the app is waiting for review

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

I submitted my app a few days ago and it is "Waiting for Review". I realized that I needed to change my Bundle Display Name (the text that shows under the app). Is there a way to change this on iTunes connect or do I have to submit a new binary.

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about iTunes Connect, not programming.

Comment: You can check this link for more info on how to change the display name...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20182852/ios-change-app-name-for-homescreen-and-spotlight. But as others have stated, you have two choices: let the app go through and change the name on your next version or reject it and resubmit. If you have just uploaded then you can reject but if it's been a week or so, then I would suggest you let it go through and update it right away using the link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an Info.plist setting, and you can't change with without submitting a new binary, since the Info.plist is part of the binary.

Comment: If you _were_ somehow able to change it remotely, your app would not launch, since the checksum would fail (the test to make sure that your files are the same as when you submitted them).

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to submit a new binary. The Display Bundle Name must be specified in your app's `info.plist` file prior to uploading.

Answer (score 1):

You can reject the old binary, fix the display name and resubmit. No way to change it now with the old binary.